# Replace String ${SPACE} not norking on a linux environment

Tags: python, linux, windows, robotframework

This is rather straight forward : I implemented my tests cases on windows environment (requirement from the employer) but now I am trying to integrate this with CI/CD  on gitlab. So the executed tests are ran on a linux OS.

With Windows doing :

```
     ${stripped_string}=     Replace String     ${string_with_space}    ${SPACE}${SPACE}     ${EMPTY}
```

Will actually remove the two spaces in my string which is not the case when running the same test case on linux.

I even tried doing `${SPACE * 2}` , still that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because whitespace characters are interpreted in a different way on Windows and Linux.

Try to Normalize line endings by doing this for example:

```
${normalized_string}=    Replace String    ${original_string}    \r\n    \n
```

Or you can just Explicitly specify spaces by using `" "` instead of `${SPACE}${SPACE}`

```
${stripped_string}=    Replace String    ${original_string}    "  "    ""
```

Comment: I actually solved this issue by moving from robot framework 5.xx to 4.xx.